# Using UIDynamics gravity to animate CGRects

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uikit-dynamics

My goal is to have a bunch of `UIViews` that have a property of `CGRect` falling from offscreen and then piling up. Right now, I have one circle working, but every time I try to add another circle, they won't animate anymore. I am using `UIDynamics` and its `gravity` function.  Here is my code:

```
func addBox(location: CGRect) -> UIView {
    let newBox = UIView(frame: location)
    newBox.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 186.0/255.0, green: 216.0/255.0, blue: 242.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    newBox.layer.cornerRadius = newBox.frame.width/2

    hView.insertSubview(newBox, at: 0)

    return newBox
}


addBox(location: CGRect(x: 100, y: -100, width: 100, height: 100))    

var animator: UIDynamicAnimator? = nil;
let gravity = UIGravityBehavior()
var collision: UICollisionBehavior!
animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: hView)

func createAnimatorStuff(box: UIView) {
    collision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [box])
    collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true
    animator?.addBehavior(collision)

    gravity.addItem(box)
    gravity.gravityDirection = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0.8)
    animator?.addBehavior(gravity)

}

func dropDown() {
    let xVal = 100
    let xVal2 = 700

    let box = addBox(location: CGRect(x: xVal, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    let box2 = addBox(location: CGRect(x: xVal2, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    createAnimatorStuff(box: box)
    createAnimatorStuff(box: box2)
}
dropDown()
```

If anyone could help me and adjust my code to create more circles falling and then piling up I would immensely appreciate it. Truly. Please ask any questions and thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

(NOTE: the question was updated with these suggestions, so that's why it appears to suggest things that were already done)

The general problem you are having is that you made `box` a global variable and you keep reinitializing the `UIDynamicAnimator`. So ...

Remove the box var, then

Change:

```
func addBox(location: CGRect)
```

to:

```
func addBox(location: CGRect) -> UIView
```

and `return newBox` at the end.

Then, change:

```
func createAnimatorStuff() {
```

to:

```
func createAnimatorStuff(box: UIView) {
```

and

```
addBox(location: CGRect(x: xVal, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
createAnimatorStuff()
```

To

```
let box = addBox(location: CGRect(x: xVal, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
createAnimatorStuff(box: box)
```

Finally, don't create a new `UIDynamicAnimator` for every call -- make one and share it.  You can do this with

```
let animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: hView)
```

(also, you don't need semicolons in Swift)

Comment: Thanks a ton! It works just like it normally does, but how would I go about adding another box. I tried adding one in `dropDown` but it stopped all animation. Do I make another function? Define a new `addBox`?

Comment: You should post your new code as an edit to the question.

Comment: just did! sorry i should have done that in the first place

Comment: You didn't remove `animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: hView);` as I suggested.  initialize it outside of the function so that it's done only once.

Comment: Is this in a playground? If so, are you using a liveView? If so, did you also set up needsIndefiniteExecution?

Comment: Yes I am and yes I did!